# Which characters in urls cause file_get_contents / curl to fail?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

I would like to know *which* characters in a url cause file_get_contents / curl to fail.

In the example below, the only character which causes a problem is the space, so the best thing for me to do would simply be to `str_replace` spaces in the url with `%20`. Are there any other characters which also cause it to fail? If so, what are they? Is there a function which does this replacement for me?

---

**ORIGINAL PHRASING:**

I'd like to be able to download an arbitrary file by its URL, chosen by the user, and have access to it as a string. My initial reaction was:

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
```

However, this fails on URLs like:

`http://i.ebayimg.com/t/2-WAY-PHOTO-FRAME-KEY-BOX-SHABBY-CHIC-STYLE-/00/s/NjAwWDYwMA==/$(KGrHqRHJDoE-PBe-SSLBPlrnIYb Q~~60_35.JPG`

Next, I tried `cURL`:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

However, for the same URL, cURL fails with "Invalid URL".

I've read on a number of questions here that when downloading from URLs with arbitrary characters in them, urlencode must be used. However, this results in:

`http%3A%2F%2Fi.ebayimg.com%2Ft%2F2-WAY-PHOTO-FRAME-KEY-BOX-SHABBY-CHIC-STYLE-%2F00%2Fs%2FNjAwWDYwMA%3D%3D%2F%24%28KGrHqRHJDoE-PBe-SSLBPlrnIYb+Q%7E%7E60_35.JPG`

which doesn't fetch either, using either method, I think because now it thinks it's a local file. What do I need to do to be able to fetch an arbitrary url?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://i.ebayimg.com/t/2-WAY-PHOTO-FRAME-KEY-BOX-SHABBY-CHIC-STYLE-/00/s/NjAwWDYwMA==/$(" . urlencode("KGrHqRHJDoE-PBe-SSLBPlrnIYb Q~~60_35.JPG");

$str = file_get_contents($url);
```

Edit: As Galen said the only problem with URL is the space and it can be fixed using str_replace as below.

```
$url = "http://i.ebayimg.com/t/2-WAY-PHOTO-FRAME-KEY-BOX-SHABBY-CHIC-STYLE-/00/s/NjAwWDYwMA==/$(KGrHqRHJDoE-PBe-SSLBPlrnIYb Q~~60_35.JPG";
$url = str_replace(' ', '+', $url);
$str = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: what about more generally? You're given `$url`. Now what?

Comment: use urlencode only to segments after domain name. i.e. text between all slashes.
e.g. www.domain.com/urlendocde(sometext)/urlencode(sometext)

Comment: The only issue with the url is that one space before the Q

Comment: Edited my answer above to fix the space problem

Comment: Thanks. I think perhaps I wasn't communicating my question effectively, so I've added a paragraph to the top of the question which I hope does a better job of getting at what I'm trying to figure out.